# Create new table by combining two existing (insert two foreign keys)

Tags: mysql, insert, foreign-keys, sql-update

I created a table that consists of two foreign keys. I want to fill the table with default values from the two related tables. They look like this:

```
+---------------+
| Table A       |
+---------------+
| id            |
| other info... |
+---------------+

+---------------+
| Table B       |
+---------------+
| id            |
| level         |
| other info... |
+---------------+
```

I want the new table to be populated so that every A has a relation to every B. How can I do this with a MySQL UPDATE statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
insert into AB select a.id, b.id from A join B;
```

Comment: Thanks! Knew it had to be somewhat easy. This is what I used: INSERT INTO C (id1, id2) SELECT a.id, b.id from A a JOIN B b;